# If I change my computer time, will it change the time I used VPN?

Tags: vpn

The company I work at monitors VPN usage from hour a, to hour b.

If we go over the allotted hours limit, we get an e-mail from IT that we're using too much VPN time.

If I change my computer timezone to something outside those hours, then login to the company VPN. Would that help me bypass the allotted VPN hours?

Changing the time itself is not allowed for my group policy.

Comment: Who checks the time and from what clock? If the server checks time from its own clock, then no.

Comment: Can you not just be more effective in your use of the VPN...i.e. login to VPN do some uploads/downloads/whatever, logoff VPN work offline, then go back online etc ad infinitum. Or work less?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VPN logs do not dictate time off of your computer, they dictate timestamps when the server gets connected to. So however, the sever is set-up, that will be the correct timestamp for login/logoff. Your computer has no control over the timestamps.